# Ant Design - emphasize matching TreeNode based on custom search filter in TreeSelect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to use custom filterTreeNode function which in my case filters nodes based on title and regardless locale letters (it's exact extension of default filtering based on title). The problem is that I am not able to emphasize matching nodes.

Here is my example: https://codesandbox.io/s/tree-select-custom-filtertreenode-8zxgy

Pay attention that I'm using treeNodeFilterProp="title" to gain some desired user experience, but it's not enough in my case.

When I'm typing "aaa" my nodes are filtering properly and the "aaaą" node is emphasized (due to treeNodeFiltersProp).

[image: emphasized node]

But when I'm writing "aaaa" my node is still showing up but is not emphasized, which is not exactly what I wanted.

[image: nonemphasied node]

So how to do this?

Comment: it seams like a problem with antd. you may raise a issue there or ask in the antd discussions (https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/discussions) as the developery may answer this.

Answer (score 0):

problem seams to be in

https://github.com/react-component/tree-select/blob/abba52deff6cfb8d38758ad3fa0af35b327fa555/src/OptionList.tsx#L137

as it overrides the `filterTreeNode` function this is why it isn't bold.

---

For option filtering the given function is used, this is why it is showing:

https://github.com/react-component/tree-select/blob/7b020ccc0156b89a9006f76627d2ccbcd14cddcc/src/generate.tsx#L546